# Multiple Projects with one package name in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, package

I have a Android Project with an unique Package name. It is also available in Google Play Store. But now I need a huge change over the App. So what do I do to avoid collision in Play store. Also in my local machine do I need to change the Package name because I am using GCM for push notification as well.

Any solution for this or I have to use the old code and change all things .

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change the package name then you can achieve it by adding more product flavors in your app.

You will need to make the following modifications in your build.gradle

```
 productFlavors {


        appWithOldPackageName{
            applicationId = "your.existing.package.name"

        }
        // This specifies the configuration of GHS android for huddle one devices
        appWithNewPackageName{
            applicationId = "your.new.package.name"
}
}
```

Comment: After doing this..When I ll upload the APK into playstore should it manage its self ? Or anything else I have to do..

Comment: U said you want to upload it as a separate app hence I gave this solution. There will APKs generated for each product flavor. If you upload appWithOldPackageNameRelease.apk to play store it will an update but if you upload appWithNewPackageNameRelease.apk to play store it will be a new application.

Comment: In local machine I want another App becuase in the old one the code structure is poor. But in Playstore it will be same . That's why I m bit confused what to do...whether to modify the old App or to create a new one.

Comment: If that is the case then you need keep the same package name, thats it. Just create a new project locally. Just use the same key to sign the apk.